# VIN scanning library or SDK for android

Tags: android

I am working on one android application which requires VIN scanning. I didn't found any good library or sdk for the same. I tried Zxing but it doesn't do VIN scanning. Can anybody help me out to implement VIN scanning in my app. Any sdk or library will be preferable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is now a google vision api, https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/requests-and-responses, which I've tested a little bit. The images needs to be cropped around the text to really nail it, but it works very well in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  it seems that you looking for OCR solution - but it will be really difficult  to provide good image from metall embossing.   You may try our OCR library for android - you shal be able to train recognition for small amount of  different fonts

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: Most vehicles have a bar code representation of the VIN for scanning. The original poster is probably looking for a bar code scanner that will read the odd 17 characters of the VIN. As of yet, I have not come across one that works well. This thread on SO shows some folks having success with zxing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535445/is-there-any-java-library-to-read-the-vin-number-barcodes-from-image